# How to sum elements of Vec<Vec<f64>> together into a Vec<f64>?

Tags: rust

I am looking for an "rusty" way to accumulate a Vec<Vec> into a Vec such that the 1st element of every inner Vec is summed together, every 2nd element of each Vec is summed together, etc..., and the results are collected into a Vec?  If I just use sum(), fold(), or accumulate() I believe I will sum entire 1st Vec together into a single element, rather than the 1st element of each inner Vec contained in the 2D Vec.

```
pub fn main() {
    let v1 = vec![1.1, 2.2, 3.3];
    let vv = vec![v1; 3];
    let desired_result = vec![3.3, 6.6, 9.9];
}
```

Comment: I had considered doing a vv.iter().flatten(), combined with a step_by(innerVec.len()), but that seems clunky

Comment: Is there a way you can build the original `Vec<Vec<_>>`  by column instead of by row? Maybe try using [`ndarray`](https://lib.rs/crates/ndarray)?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I will receive my data as a Vec<Vec<_>>, I am not in control of the format I receive the data in.

Comment: Where does the data come from? If you're deserializing it from some input, `ndarray` supports `serde`.

Comment: shared mem ipc.

Comment: Is either dimension constant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes it's easy to forget in Rust that the imperative approach exists and is an easy solution.

```rust
let mut sums = vec![0.0; vv[0].len()];
for v in vv {
    for (i, x) in v.into_iter().enumerate() {
        sums[i] += x;
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, you are correct.  Very easy to forget.

Comment: If there is not a functional solution forthcoming soon, I will mark this as the answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer this was the best solution as I do need this to be as performant as possible as it is in the main loop of my program

Answer (score 2):

While I prefer @orlp's solution, if you're hell-bent on doing this the most functionally possible, you could do it like this:

```
let v1 = vec![1.1, 2.2, 3.3];
let vv = vec![v1; 3];
let sums = vec![0.0; vv[0].len()];
let summed = vv.into_iter().fold(sums, |mut sums, v| {
    v.into_iter().enumerate().for_each(|(i, x)| sums[i] += x);
    sums
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if knowing beforehand the size of the inner vectors (or taking it from the first occurence in the `vv` vector), you can use a range iterator:

```rust
pub fn main() {
    let v1 = vec![1.1, 2.2, 3.3];
    let v1_len = v1.len();
    let vv = vec![v1; 3];
    let res: Vec<f64> = (0..v1_len)
        .map(|i| vv.iter().map(|v| v.get(i).unwrap()).sum())
        .collect();
    println!("{res:?}");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0190154fc97b4ee2cf3c1bfb6eaa9e94)

Comment: I'd just like to note that if you care about performance that the memory access pattern of this is significantly worse than my answer.